# Get orders by shipping region ids

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, collection

I wanted orders collection by shipping region id. What I have done:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->getLastItem();
print_r($order->getData());
```

When I do `print_r` the order data, so `region_id` is not accessible otherwise I would have used `addAttributeToFilter()` or `addFieldToFilter()`.

`region_id` is accessible on the `print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData());`

How can I add `region_id` in the filter?

***Edited***

I want something like this

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('region_id',517)
```

all orders whose shipping region id is 517.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get filter the `order` collection by `region_id` like this

```
$ordercollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$ordercollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id',array('region_id'=>'sfoa.region_id'));
$ordercollection->addFieldToFilter('region_id',array('eq'=>'32'));
echo "<pre>";print_r($ordercollection->getData());
```

Note : 32 here is the `region_id` by which you can filter your orders.

Comment: no.. i want something like this Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('region_id',517)

Comment: Check my updated answer